# setting library versions issue

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-dependencies

Setting the right versions for Gradle dependencies has always seemed, to me, to be an arcane science. For instance take the following line . . .

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:+'
```

If I build the project with that line I get version 12.0.1 which should be the latest version.  No?

If I place my cursor on the + and hit alt-enter and choose "Replace with specific version" I get version 2.1.0.  I recall reading somewhere that I should get the latest version stated specifically instead of, in this case, 2.1.0.

So I guess the most dependable way to find the latest version of a library is to compile with + and look to see what I get.

Comment: One option is to check maven repositories (e.g. https://bintray.com/firebaseui/firebase-ui/firebase-ui) to see which versions are actually available. I'm not sure I understand how you see either 12.0.1 or 2.1.0 as the latest in your application given that 3.3.0 looks newer.

Answer (score 0):

When there is an update android studio show a warning and a mouse over is enough to show you the latest library.

This works great for all google-android components.

For other third party libraries I usually add a link comment in order to check regularly if there is something new.

Note that in the white theme the warnings are not so clear as in the black theme.

[image: android-studio-warning]